# Individual node coloring of predefined graphs from TikZ-berge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

So far your forum has given me all the information I needed for TeX. Thanks for that. Now, it is the first time, I have a question, I couldn't find an answer to:

I want to draw graphs of the Platonic Solids. Luckily, their graphs are all given in the [`tkz-berge`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/doc/tkz-berge-screen.pdf) library. 
One goal is colouring all nodes that have the same distance to a node with the same colour. The problem is now, that I don't manage to colour the nodes independently of each other.

I give some sample code below. I would like to have nodes 2,3 and 4 with a different fill colour, e.g. like: `fill=red!20`.

Would be great if anyone could help me, otherwise I would have to draw the graphs all from scratch.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
ecke/.style={circle,draw=blue!60,fill=blue!20,thick, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{VertexStyle}=[ecke]
  \SetVertexNoLabel %there are default labels in the \grTetrahedral-command.
  \grTetrahedral[RA=4]
  \AssignVertexLabel{a}{1,2,3,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\AddVertexColor` command. You should do so before assigning the labels, or the labels will not be shown. The prefix of your graph is `a`, so the vertices are named `a0` to `a3`. So the command you need is :

```
\AddVertexColor{red!20}{a1,a2,a3}
```

Comment: Nice, and a red border can be added by style injection: `\AddVertexColor{red!20, draw=red!60}{a1, a2, a3}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Heiko and Tonio! Especially for the quick and clear response!